# Difference between the Likelihood Function for $\mu$ and Sampling Distribution of Sample Mean

Tags: distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood

### Background:

Suppose I have **2** random observations from a ***normal density function*** whose $\sigma = 2$. The first observation is $x_1 = 6$. The second observation is $x_2 = 8$. The question below arises from this context I just described.

### Question:

Below, I am wondering if I am understanding the difference between the ***Likelihood Function*** for $(\mu)$ and the ***Sampling Distribution*** of Sample Mean $(\bar{x})$? Specifically, does my R code below accurately show the difference between these two statistical concepts?

**Here is my R code:**

```
SIGMA = 2                  # Population SIGMA known
observations = c(6, 8)     # observations drawn
n = length(observations)   # number of observations
x_bar = mean(observations) # mean of observations
SE = SIGMA / sqrt(n)       # 'S'tandard 'E'rror of the mean

Likelihood = function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = observations, SIGMA), prod) # multiplication of densities to obtain Likelihood values

curve(Likelihood, from = -1, to = 15, col = 'red', lwd = 3) # Likelihood function of MU

curve(dnorm(x, x_bar, SE), add = T, col = 'blue', lty = 2 ) # Sampling Distribution of x_bar
```

Comment: Not quite.  The sampling distribution of $\bar{x}$ depends on the true parameter values, and should be centered at the true mean, whereas in your code you have it centered at the (observed) sample mean.  The likelihood function is right, though.

Comment: @jbowman, thanks, but when population $(\mu)$ is unknown, how a sampling distribution can be formed? And how can I get a CI from that sampling distribution?

Comment: You can't.  What people do, however, is they a) either become Bayesians, which results in a qualitatively different solution than what you are seeking, or b) they kind-of reverse the problem.  The reversed problem forms the sampling distribution of unobserved $\bar{x}$ assuming the population parameters equal the observed / known parameters, and the statement you make based on that is something like "If the pop. mean were $\bar{x}$, the sample mean would lie in (this interval) 95% of the time."

Comment: But it is not something that can be turned into a statement such as "95% of the time the pop. mean will be in this interval, given that I observed $\bar{x}$."

Comment: @jbowman, that was really enlightening! Suppose I just became a Bayesian ! Now, I put a flat prior on $(\mu)$. How come the percentile-based 95% interval from the posterior (which is essentially the likelihood function in this case), equals the 95% Interval using the imaginary sampling distribution you just described?

Comment: @jbowman, that is, is the imaginary sampling distribution you just described = the likelihood function? This might be shown using my R code in my question, right?